# How can I create a QR code with Firebase?

Tags: qr-code, firebase-mlkit

Is it possible to create a QR code with Firebase?

I'd like to create a QR code for sharing pdf files with other people. It seems the Firebase has such functions but I couldn't figure it out where to generate the code...

Comment: Welcome to SO. [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) is a [NoSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) database and doesn't create QR codes. The QR Code can be created in your app and *stored* in Firebase. iOS has a built-in QR code generator; it's a little tricky when first starting but there are a number of tutorials available. Take a minute and review the following guides about asking questions : [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Jay This is a valid question. Firebase is not just a database. As Firebase Mobile Vision provides a feature for scanning QR codes and Zxing is in maintenance mode only, this question stands valid.

Comment: @MonishKamble Thanks for your comment and observation. Take another look at the question; it's almost a year old (2018), it's tagged Firebase NoSQL Database (see the tag) and it's being asked if *Firebase* can **create** QR codes (not scan them), which it can't - it can't do either. Also the product you mention *Firebase Mobile Vision* is part of [ML Kit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/) which is a totally separate product from the Firebase Database and has it's own tag: firebase-mlkit. If it was regarding ML Kit, perhaps that tag should be added but it's unclear from the question.

Comment: @Jay Thanks for correcting me. My bad, I didn't checked the question history.

Answer (score 0):

Since Firebase ML-Kit was tagged I'm going to assume this question is specifically about Firebase ML-Kit. Firebase ML-Kit has a barcode scanning API but Firebase **does not** have a way to create/generate QR codes.

See Firebase ML-Kit:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/read-barcodes

Answer (score 0):

Firebase integrates Google Cloud Functions and Cloud Storage.  A straightforward way to generate a QR code could be writing a cloud function that takes the input of your call from Firebase, writes the QR code image to your Firebase connected cloud storage, and then returns the URI of the image.

Firebase Cloud Functions "provides a way to extend the behavior of Firebase and integrate Firebase features through the addition of server-side code."[source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/functions-and-firebase)

So, unlike GCP Cloud Functions that can be written in multiple languages, you typically will write Typescript or Javascript only on Firebase Functions.

### Example QR Code Generation Code

#### Example Code for `node.js`

```js
// index.js -> bundle.js
var QRCode = require('qrcode')
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')

QRCode.toCanvas(canvas, 'sample text', function (error) {
  if (error) console.error(error)
  console.log('success!');
})
```

### Documentation References

[npm QR Code Generator Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode)

[Firebase Functions Getting Started Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started)